# calculate volume area of a bursted utilization distribution using the 'move' package

Tags: r, move

I applied the brownian.bridge.dyn() function to a ‘MoveBurst’ object. I then re-standardized this object so that the bursted segments sum to 1 and to avoid rounding issues. I would now like to calculate the volume of the UD using the getVolumeUD() function but this doesn’t seem to work as the re-standardised UD is of class ‘list’.

The code is shown below:

```
library(move)
    
move.ind <- move(x=ind$Lon,y=ind$Lat,time=ind$Datetime,
                 proj=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"),
                 data=ind,animal=ind$Tag,sensor="VR2W")

move.ind$LocationError = 1 

r.ind <- spTransform(move.ind,center=TRUE)

TimeDiff <- timeLag(r.ind, units="hours")
r.ind$TimeDiff <- append(0,TimeDiff)

e <- 5000
xUTM.ind <- raster(xmn=min(ind$NewEastingUTM)-e, xmx=max(ind$NewEastingUTM)+e, ymn=min(ind$NewNorthingUTM)-e, 
                   ymx=max(ind$NewNorthingUTM)+e,crs =CRS("+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84"), 
                   resolution=50)

x.ind <- raster(xmn=min(DET$NewEastingUTM),xmx=max(DET$NewEastingUTM),ymn=min(DET$NewNorthingUTM),
                ymx=max(DET$NewNorthingUTM),crs=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84"))
proj4string(x.ind)

newTemplate <- projectExtent(xUTM.ind,proj4string(x.ind))

ones = rep(1, (newTemplate@ncols*newTemplate@nrows))
xAEQD.ind <- setValues(newTemplate, ones)

rNew.ind <- spTransform(r.ind, proj4string(xAEQD.ind))

bursted <- burst(rNew.ind, c('normal','long')[1+(timeLag(rNew.ind, units = 'hours')>4)]) 

bursted_dbbmm <- brownian.bridge.dyn(bursted, burstType='normal', raster = xAEQD.ind, 
                                     location.error = "LocationError", time.step = 5, ext = 3,
                                     window.size = 29)

tmp <- calc(bursted_dbbmm,sum)
dbbmmlist <- new(".UD",tmp/sum(values(tmp)))

cont.ind <- getVolumeUD(dbbmmlist)
```

dummy code is shown below:

```
ind <- structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1343535240, 1343539560, 
1343543880, 1343548200, 1343622480, 1343625120, 1343628540, 1343630280, 
1343634600, 1343634600, 1343640660, 1343644980, 1343655360, 1343656200, 
1343661360, 1343665680, 1343671740, 1343707200, 1343709780, 1343711520, 
1343714100, 1343715840, 1343717520, 1343718420, 1343721000, 1343721840, 
1343722740, 1343722740, 1343723580, 1343725320, 1343727060), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "US/Eastern"), Tag = c(437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 
437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 
437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 
437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L), Lat = c(25.73785, 25.73779, 25.73822, 
25.73803, 25.7387, 25.73772, 25.73842, 25.73759, 25.73693, 25.73765, 
25.73781, 25.73819, 25.73975, 25.73766, 25.73803, 25.73758, 25.73799, 
25.74314, 25.73943, 25.74317, 25.7407, 25.74324, 25.73739, 25.74175, 
25.71287, 25.73699, 25.73749, 25.74292, 25.73809, 25.743, 25.74249
), Lon = c(-79.24489, -79.24543, -79.24039, -79.24479, -79.24606, 
-79.24551, -79.23763, -79.24604, -79.24535, -79.24622, -79.24678, 
-79.24583, -79.24725, -79.2454, -79.24459, -79.24632, -79.24553, 
-79.24629, -79.24731, -79.24647, -79.24724, -79.24652, -79.24577, 
-79.24749, -79.24636, -79.24537, -79.24547, -79.24742, -79.24582, 
-79.2464, -79.24771), NewEastingUTM = c(676052.593850702, 675998.505006306, 
676503.524589617, 676062.361342852, 675933.957732871, 675990.581885337, 
676780.134256345, 675937.599356069, 676007.79854611, 675919.451865544, 
675863.032391998, 675957.784408548, 675813.022339476, 676001.706417219, 
676082.426966281, 675909.522121439, 675988.177486275, 675904.342388974, 
675807.473799857, 675886.239923252, 675812.627071404, 675881.120633141, 
675964.982682709, 675786.000042484, 675941.884041032, 676005.703553397, 
675994.93392188, 675791.30042537, 675958.935010342, 675893.512994838, 
675762.839399625), NewNorthingUTM = c(2847824.10140759, 2847816.73427449, 
2847871.10249762, 2847844.17392274, 2847916.6963574, 2847808.8734514, 
2847896.95405131, 2847793.76586291, 2847721.57691275, 2847800.1720647, 
2847817.14869788, 2847860.50938921, 2848031.42006168, 2847802.37392041, 
2847844.44095791, 2847792.28461383, 2847838.75526749, 2848408.21836108, 
2847995.89296004, 2848411.30139552, 2848136.66700018, 2848418.98875582, 
2847771.97165951, 2848252.64452269, 2845055.05409167, 2847728.1965547, 
2847783.44921703, 2848382.34136664, 2847849.44550836, 2848392.56348938, 
2848334.32268777)), row.names = c(NA, 31L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried reproducing your issue. However your code does not seem to run directly (DET is absent, your data contains missing data) so I fixed it with some different settings. However this does not show your problem (with the development version of move):

```r
library(move)
#> Loading required package: geosphere
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Loading required package: raster
#> Loading required package: rgdal
#> rgdal: version: 1.5-23, (SVN revision 1121)
#> Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
#> Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
#> Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal
#> GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
#> Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]
#> Path to PROJ shared files: /usr/share/proj
#> Linking to sp version:1.4-5
#> To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
#> use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.


ind <- structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(
  1343535240, 1343539560,
  1343543880, 1343548200, 1343622480, 1343625120, 1343628540, 1343630280,
  1343634600, 1343634600, 1343640660, 1343644980, 1343655360, 1343656200,
  1343661360, 1343665680, 1343671740, 1343707200, 1343709780, 1343711520,
  1343714100, 1343715840, 1343717520, 1343718420, 1343721000, 1343721840,
  1343722740, 1343722740, 1343723580, 1343725320, 1343727060
), class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
), tzone = "US/Eastern"), Tag = c(
  437L, 437L, 437L, 437L,
  437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L,
  437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L,
  437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L
), Lat = c(
  25.73785, 25.73779, 25.73822,
  25.73803, 25.7387, 25.73772, 25.73842, 25.73759, 25.73693, 25.73765,
  25.73781, 25.73819, 25.73975, 25.73766, 25.73803, 25.73758, 25.73799,
  25.74314, 25.73943, 25.74317, 25.7407, 25.74324, 25.73739, 25.74175,
  25.71287, 25.73699, 25.73749, 25.74292, 25.73809, 25.743, 25.74249
), Lon = c(
  -79.24489, -79.24543, -79.24039, -79.24479, -79.24606,
  -79.24551, -79.23763, -79.24604, -79.24535, -79.24622, -79.24678,
  -79.24583, -79.24725, -79.2454, -79.24459, -79.24632, -79.24553,
  -79.24629, -79.24731, -79.24647, -79.24724, -79.24652, -79.24577,
  -79.24749, -79.24636, -79.24537, -79.24547, -79.24742, -79.24582,
  -79.2464, -79.24771
), NewEastingUTM = c(
  676052.593850702, 675998.505006306,
  676503.524589617, 676062.361342852, 675933.957732871, 675990.581885337,
  676780.134256345, 675937.599356069, 676007.79854611, 675919.451865544,
  675863.032391998, 675957.784408548, 675813.022339476, 676001.706417219,
  676082.426966281, 675909.522121439, 675988.177486275, 675904.342388974,
  675807.473799857, 675886.239923252, 675812.627071404, 675881.120633141,
  675964.982682709, 675786.000042484, 675941.884041032, 676005.703553397,
  675994.93392188, 675791.30042537, 675958.935010342, 675893.512994838,
  675762.839399625
), NewNorthingUTM = c(
  2847824.10140759, 2847816.73427449,
  2847871.10249762, 2847844.17392274, 2847916.6963574, 2847808.8734514,
  2847896.95405131, 2847793.76586291, 2847721.57691275, 2847800.1720647,
  2847817.14869788, 2847860.50938921, 2848031.42006168, 2847802.37392041,
  2847844.44095791, 2847792.28461383, 2847838.75526749, 2848408.21836108,
  2847995.89296004, 2848411.30139552, 2848136.66700018, 2848418.98875582,
  2847771.97165951, 2848252.64452269, 2845055.05409167, 2847728.1965547,
  2847783.44921703, 2848382.34136664, 2847849.44550836, 2848392.56348938,
  2848334.32268777
)), row.names = c(NA, 31L), class = "data.frame")


ind<-ind[-28,][-10,]


move.ind <- move(
  x = ind$Lon, y = ind$Lat, time = ind$Datetime,
  proj = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"),
  data = ind, animal = ind$Tag, sensor = "VR2W"
)

move.ind$LocationError <- 1

r.ind <- spTransform(move.ind, center = TRUE)

rNew.ind <- spTransform(r.ind, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84"))

bursted <- burst(rNew.ind, c("normal", "long")[1 + (timeLag(rNew.ind, units = "hours") > 4)])

bursted_dbbmm <- brownian.bridge.dyn(bursted,raster = 50,
                                     burstType = "normal",# raster = xAEQD.ind,
                                     location.error = "LocationError", time.step = 5, ext = 3,
                                     window.size = 15, margin = 7
)
#> Warning in proj4string(object): CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> Warning in .local(object, raster, location.error = location.error, ext = ext, :
#> Some burst are omitted for variance calculation since there are not segements of
#> interest
#> Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...): CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> Computational size: 9.3e+06
#> Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...): CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> Computational size: 2.3e+06

tmp <- calc(bursted_dbbmm, sum)
dbbmmlist <- new(".UD", tmp / sum(values(tmp)))

cont.ind <- getVolumeUD(dbbmmlist)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience. Glad you got it to work. The getVolumeUD() function doesn't give any warning/error messages, however, it also don't give a calculated value for UD volume. Hence my post. I don't know how to retrieve the correct result from this function. Sorry if that was not clear previously.

Comment: The function  returns a raster with value indicating to what quantile a certain grid cell belongs. This `plot(cont.ind<.95)` for example gives the 95% ud. This generates polygons if your intrested: `rasterToPolygons(cont.ind<.95, dissolve = T)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I remembered now that I could use cont.ind<=.95 to calculate the area covered within the contours using sum(values(cont.ind<=.95)). Thank you!